# Do I still need original diablo 3 to play reaper of souls?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm planning to buy Diablo 3 game, and I was just wondering, because I found two diablo's basically, the original and Reaper of souls.

My question is :

Do I still need original diablo 3 to play reaper of souls? In other words, should I buy the two editions, or will the reaper of souls also contain the diablo game base. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you need to buy both, unless it's for a console.

Reaper of Souls is just an expansion and doesn't include the base game. Consoles have The Ultimate Evil edition, which includes both the base game and the expansion.

You can play the original Diablo 3 without the expansion however and buy the expansion later. The expansion content isn't unlocked until you complete the original content at least once, so you can buy the base game and figure out if you enjoy the game or not before buying the expansion.

Comment: Is this for PC or for all consoles?

Comment: PC, consoles have The Ultimate Evil edition, which includes the base game and the expansion together, I am not entirely sure if consoles have Reaper of Souls available separately or not...

Comment: Yeah, I can't seem to find a console version other than The Ultimate Evil edition, so I guess there is no expansion-only version for consoles.

Comment: Ok, that answers my question, thanks. Interesting though that they would not release it as a downloadable expansion package for console though..?

Comment: @Ben vanilla Diablo 3 was drastically changed when Reaper of Souls was released. I'd guess that it was too much effort to patch the original Diablo 3 console release to be compatible with Reaper of Souls, so it was easier for them to just release a new game that contained the expansion.

Comment: I would not get it on consoles. It has no seasons and is inferior to PC imho.